# How can I get data from JSON array using the array's elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

```
{
"Centers": {
    "Athens": [
        {
            "name":"name1",
            "lat":"",
            "lon":"",
            "address":"address1",
            "tel":"",
            "email":"",
            "link":""
        },
        {
            "name":"name2",
            "lat":"",
            "lon":"",
            "address":"address2",
            "tel":"",
            "email":"",
            "link":""
        }       
    ]
}
}
```

I have this JSON file and I want to get the address of an element I specify using its name.
Something like this:

```
alert( stores.Centers.Athens["name"=="name1"].address );
```

Is there any way I can achieve this, or should I remake my JSON file?

**Edit:**

`.find(x => x.name === 'name1')`  doesn't work. It returns 'undefined'. `findIndex()` also returns '-1'. I suspect it's because it is a JSON file and not an object list, meaning the property keys are doublequoted.

Comment: "_`.find(x => x.name === 'name1')` doesn't work._" [Yes it does](https://jsfiddle.net/j1a0do4n/). If stores contains the properly parsed JSON, it should work fine. If it isn't properly parsed, then `stores.Centers` should already be `undefined`. You'll need to provide a [mcve] for us to be able to help you further.

Answer (score -1):

You can easiy achieve the result using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
stores.Centers.Athens.find((o) => o.name === "name1")?.address
```

```js
const stores = {
  Centers: {
    Athens: [
      {
        name: "name1",
        lat: "",
        lon: "",
        address: "address1",
        tel: "",
        email: "",
        link: "",
      },
      {
        name: "name2",
        lat: "",
        lon: "",
        address: "address2",
        tel: "",
        email: "",
        link: "",
      },
    ],
  },
};
const address = stores.Centers.Athens.find((o) => o.name === "name1")?.address;
console.log(address);
```

Comment: doesn't work, maybe because JSON files habe the property keys doublequoted.

Comment: doesn't matter. Please add your code at `Codesandbox` and let me see. What I can do for you